# Accessing elements of a Clojure map in a vector of maps

Tags: clojure

I have:

```
(def moo (my-func))
```

which returns:

```
[{:id 1 :name "Bob"}
 {:id 2 :name "Jane"}
 {:id 3 :name "Greg"}]
```

How do I now access moo to get the `:name` where `:id=3`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather prefer using `some` (since it is more logical than using `filter` i guess, because it is designed to find exactly one value):

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :name "Bob"}
   {:id 2 :name "Jane"}
   {:id 3 :name "Greg"}])

(defn name-by-id [id data]
  (some #(when (= (:id %) id) (:name %)) data))

user> 
(name-by-id 3 data)
"Greg"
user> 
(name-by-id 100 data)
nil
```

Comment: I haven't run any benchmarks but `some` is probably faster than `(comp first filter)` since it doesn't create an intermediate lazy-seq. (Note that `data` is not a lazy-seq in the answer, but it could be in the OP's version.)

Comment: i guess it is. But first of all it is specially designed for this exact task

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a `filter`

```
(def moos
  [{:id 1 :name "Bob"}
   {:id 2 :name "Jane"}
   {:id 3 :name "Greg"}])

(defn name-for-id
  [id]
  (:name (first (filter #(= (:id %) id) moos))))

(name-for-id 3) ; => "Greg"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(def names
  [{:id 1 :name "Bob"}
   {:id 2 :name "Jane"}
   {:id 3 :name "Greg"}])

;;get the :name where :id=3
(defn answer []
  (:name (first (filter (fn [e] (= 3 (:id e))) names))))
```

In the above rather than `names` you could have `moo`.